# How should a request letter from employer look like

Tags: working-visas, usa, mexican-citizens

I am a Mexican citizen and have a job offer from a US company. I was wondering how a request letter from my employer (so I can take it to my visa application interview) should look like. Will the offer letter itself suffice?

FYI: I'm applying for a TN-1 Visa

Comment: @MichaelHampton, that's not such good advice. I think it also requires at least an end date (not more than 3 years out), a position description showing the job is one requiring a NAFTA professional, and the qualifications he needs for the work (e.g. a relevant degree), which he'll need to prove he has to obtain the visa. See [here](http://tnvisa.blogspot.com/2011/07/about-tn-visa_09.html?m=1) for some samples.

Comment: what if the offer ive been given is *at will* @Dennis

Comment: My actual experience is more than a decade out of date but I'm pretty sure the letter needs an expected end date or time duration, for the employer to acknowledge they know your employment status is temporary (you'll need to do this again in three years), to affirm the "no immigrant intent" restriction on that visa and to tell them how long to make the visa valid for. This doesn't need to imply a contract to keep you that long (employment can still be "at will"), it just needs to acknowledge the time-limited status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the North American Free Trade Agreement (NAFTA) TN NAFTA Professionals, there are two nonimmigrant categories: [TN-1 are Canadian professionals, TN-2 are Mexican professionals](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/tn-nafta-professionals).

The employer letter, in addition to offering you the position, has to demonstrate that you meet the requirements (your education and experience) of the position, measured against the professional standards and licensure (where appropriate), and the specific knowledge, skills, or experience demanded by the specific position.

In other words, *both you and the employer have to prove the requirements have been met* and, for that reason, the employer letter should cover all the bases:

- Position being offered
- Requirements of the position (job description)
- Position is a [qualifying professions](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-11261/0-0-0-17197/0-0-0-21051.html)
- You have necessary education and/or alternative credentials (degree, certificates, diploma,  professional license)
- You have necessary experience (as demonstrated by your specifics, which it outlines)